# ClearScript ExtendedHostFunctions kills EXE when run from Task Scheduler?

Tags: c#, clearscript

In my C# project I have the following

```
    private static JScriptEngine JSE = new JScriptEngine(WindowsScriptEngineFlags.EnableDebugging | WindowsScriptEngineFlags.EnableJITDebugging);

...
        JSE.AddHostObject("CSHost", new HostFunctions());
        JSE.AddHostObject("CSExtendedHost", new ExtendedHostFunctions());
        JSE.AddHostObject("CS", new HostTypeCollection("mscorlib",
                                              "System",
                                              "System.Core",
                                              "System.Data",
                                              "RestSharp",
                                              "QuarterMaster",
                                              "AutoPlayLibrary",
                                              "ExtrasLibrary",
                                              "GoogleAdWordsLibrary",
                                              "GoogleDriveLibrary",
                                              "JSONSerialisationLibrary",
                                              "SeleniumLibrary",
                                              "WebServerLibrary",
                                              "WordPressLibrary",
                                              "WorkFlowMaxLibrary",
                                              "XeroLibrary"));
```

This works fine when run interactively. What happens when run from Task Scheduler is that the `CSHost` defines okay but the `CSExtendedHost` kills the EXE and throws errors in the Event log.

The errors in Event Viewer aren't exactly helpful, viz

```
Application: RulesetRunner.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.IO.FileLoadException
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(System.Reflection.AssemblyName, System.String, System.Security.Policy.Evidence, System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark ByRef, IntPtr, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(System.Reflection.AssemblyName, System.String, System.Security.Policy.Evidence, System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark ByRef, IntPtr, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(System.Reflection.AssemblyName, System.Security.Policy.Evidence, System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark ByRef, IntPtr, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(System.String, System.Security.Policy.Evidence, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark ByRef, IntPtr, Boolean)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(System.String, System.Security.Policy.Evidence, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark ByRef, Boolean)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(System.String)
   at Microsoft.ClearScript.HostTypeCollection.AddAssembly(System.String)
   at System.Array.ForEach[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](System.__Canon[], System.Action`1<System.__Canon>)
   at Microsoft.ClearScript.HostTypeCollection..ctor(System.String[])
   at RulesetRunner.Program.Main(System.String[])
```

It's only been through trial and error that I've established that its ExtendedHostFunctions. If I comment it out and retry something else triggers the problem, in this case `RestSharp` but the DLL is in the right place and even on the PATH.

Comment: It looks like `HostTypeCollection` is failing to load one or more of those assemblies. See if you can figure out which ones.

Comment: Well, RestSharp was one of them. As it stands, I've completely reworked the HostTypeCollection section. But it's annoying that I had to. One Azure server works, the other not. Both same Server OS.